# Tags are not registered in Azure push notifications hub

Tags: azure, notifications, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I have tried to registered tags for sending push notifications to the specific based on tag but push not working when tag base sending process is used. There is a issue with registering tags in azure push notifications hub. Here is the sample What I have tried.

Sample Code:

```
  var tags = new List<string> { userId };

        AppDelegate.Hub?.UnregisterAllAsync(AppDelegate.DeviceToken, error =>
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error calling Unregister: {0}", error);
            }

            AppDelegate.Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(AppDelegate.DeviceToken, new NSSet(tags.ToArray()), errorCallback =>
            {
                if (errorCallback != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync error: " + errorCallback.ToString());
                }
            });             
        });
```

While sending push notifications to the user I am trying fallowing code :

```
  await hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(alertJson, userId.ToString())
```

Where userId is my tag. I am fallowing these way but push notifications are not working. Can you please suggest what I am missing while registering the device in azure push notifications hub.

Comment: Do you get any errors? What exactly goes wrong? "Doesn't work" is a bit too generic for us to work with. Have you checked if the tag you provided is or isn't registered with the devices in the notification hub? Does userId have a value when it's registered?

Answer (score 0):

> Tags are not registered in Azure push notifications hub

Did you register the tag from your client app or mobile service? According to the newest version of [document](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-quickstart/blob/master/README.md#client-added-push-notification-tags), Registering tag from client app is not allowed now.

*Client-added push notification tags When a mobile app registers for push notifications using an Azure App Service Mobile Apps backend, there are two default tags that can get added to the registration in Azure Notification Hubs: the installation ID, which is unique to the app on a given device, and the user ID, which is only added when the user has been previously authenticated. **Any other tags that get supplied by the client are ignored, which is by design.** (Note that this differs from Mobile Services, where the client could supply any tag and there were hooks into the registration process on the backend to validate tags on incoming registrations.)*

To register a tag, you need to add a api from your service side. For more information, link below is for your reference.

[Adding push notification tags from an Azure Mobile Apps client](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/writingdata_services/2016/01/22/adding-push-notification-tags-from-an-azure-mobile-apps-client/)

The updating tag code could be like this,

```
// Verify that the tags are a valid JSON array.
var tags = JArray.Parse(message);

// Define a collection of PartialUpdateOperations. Note that 
// only one '/tags' path is permitted in a given collection.
var updates = new List<PartialUpdateOperation>();

// Add a update operation for the tag.
updates.Add(new PartialUpdateOperation
{
    Operation = UpdateOperationType.Add,
    Path = "/tags",
    Value = tags.ToString()
});

try
{
    // Add the requested tag to the installation.
    await hubClient.PatchInstallationAsync(Id, updates);
}
catch(MessagingException)
{
    // When an error occurs, ...
}
```